# Как установить хук на окно?

Tags: c#

Подскажите как установить хук `SetWindowsHookEx` на определённое окно, к примеру на окно `Notepad`, и проверять только его.
К примеру если я запустил блокнот активировать хук, если окно закрыто убрать хук.

Comment: Эта функция навешивает хук на уже существующее окно. То есть сперва это окно нужно найти. Вам, как я понял, нужно именно отлавливать все события создания окон. Посмотрите эту [статью](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38523/How-to-Write-a-Managed-Global-Hook-for-Window-Crea).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Да именно нужно сначала найти окно и после отлавливать все события данного окна.